# Android Studio: Android Resource Directory vs Directory

Tags: android, android-studio

What's the difference between an Android Resource Directory and a normal Directory?

[image: Android Studio Option]

**When shall I use which?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing `Android Resource Directory` will show a helper dialog by Android Studio to select pre-defined Android-specific directories as per the selected `Resource` like `layout, drawable, raw`, etc.

[image]

Whereas choosing `Directory` will show a text box dialog, where you can simply type in the name for the directory.